# Timing error when formatting a UITableView with server data (parse.com)

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm getting a really weird timing error when I'm trying to retrieve data from a server and use it to format a UITableView. When I run the code I get an empty UITableView. Below is my code and the logs.

**Code**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    __block float ans = 0;
    
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Files"];
    [query whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:[self.arr objectAtIndex:row]];
    [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
        if (!object) {
        } else {
            ans = [[object objectForKey:@"height"] intValue];
            NSLog(@"%f",ans); // log 1
        }
    }];
    NSLog(@"%f",ans); // log 2
    return ans;
}
```

**Logs**

*The second long appears a few seconds after the first. I'm guessing the second long to appear is log 1 (see code)*

> 2014-08-06 11:52:35.159 App1.0[38094:a0b] 0.000000
>
> 2014-08-06 11:52:37.470 App1.0[38094:a0b] 400.000000

Comment: You better request query outside of `UITableView delegate`. After you got response, update `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You perform the query in the background, which can take an arbitrary amount of time, and only set the height in the completion handler which is executed after the query is performed, which is most likely after the table view has already been initialised with the default value of 0 that you set before the block returned by the method.

As trick14 suggested, you better perform the query outside of the `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` table view method and then update it.

Comment: `reloadData` will invoke `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and query will be requested again. I don't think it can be an answer.